# Blogdown using Hugo - How to expand width of code chunks?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

**Problem**

The code I'm posting on my Blogdown site is too wide and induces a side scroll bar:

[image]

**Question**

How do I change the config page to make the width of text chunks wider?

I want the solution to be expanding the width of the `content` or `posts` section of Blogdown/Hugo is this possible?

I came across a few possible solutions:

1) Change the theme parameters -- not sure how to do this, but I realized this may be the only way 
2) Change Hugo themes all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to change the `max-width` argument (look for `@media (min-width: 600px) {
  section {` or something similar) inside `main.css` in your theme directory. Might be a good idea to look at your theme git for more details.

Comment: I'll try this, when I find the `@media ...` and change the width...I just save over the hugo theme file? When I `build_site()` it will accept the new hugo parameters? Or do I need to reinstall the hugo theme after changing the parameters? I'll try both, just wondering for now.

Comment: no need to reinstall--it will work after save. Which theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using lithium. And I'm just implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to disable the scroll bar, you can do these as follows:

Firstly try to find css/index.css in static dir

(1) for horizontal scroll bar

pre {

```
white-space: pre-wrap  //add this line to word wrap，disable the horizontal scroll bar
word-wrap: break-word  //add this line to word wrap，disable the horizontal scroll bar
```

}

(2) for vertical scroll bar

pre {

```
    // width: 100%  comment this line to solve the vertical problem
```

}